# Кешировать страницы с помощью XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Всё находится и запускается на одном и том же домене в последних версиях основных браузеров.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var sites = ["/page1", "/page2", "/page3"];
  var cache = {};

  function xhrStart(url) {
   xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
    }

function isOkXhr() {
return (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&
    (xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300));
     }
  function reload() {
var len = sites.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var url = sites[i];

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (isOkXhr())
            cache[url] = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xhrStart(url);
  }
  }
```

Функция reload должна бы кешировать все страницы, но на самом деле все запросы возвращают Aborted в отладчике, кроме последнего. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер правильные заголовки возвращает?

Если это не статика (на сервере), то скорее всего сервер отвечает не 304, а 200 ответом, а браузер пробует брать из кэша только при получении 304 ([304 Not Modified](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#304)).

Comment: Вроде, ошибка в том, что используется один и тот же XHR.